# Is there a way to remember the old DOM or state when navigating between pages with Python and Selenium webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have a list of courses on page A, after clicking edit for a course it takes me to page B where I perform certain actions. When clicking save and return it brings me back to page A where I want to click and edit the following item on the list. The problem is I lose the DOM or state (not sure how to reference it) of the previous item on the list, this causes my loop to break without going to the next item and performing the necessary actions.

```py
#iterate backup ul with each year and faculty
lists = ['2018-1','2017-1','2017-2','2016-2','2016-3']
faculties = ['FEA','FMSS','FNAHSW','FST','ODL']
for link_text in lists:
    link = driver.find_element_by_link_text(link_text)
    link.click()
    time.sleep(1)
    for facs in faculties:
        link = driver.find_element_by_link_text(facs)
        link.click()
        #check to see if faculties have courses
        if driver.find_element_by_class_name('dimmed').text != 0:
            #traverse course list
            resultSet = driver.find_element_by_class_name('course-list')
            options = resultSet.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")          
            #traverse and click each edit course button
            for option in options:
                time.sleep(3)
                option.find_element_by_class_name('action-edit').click()
                #inside edit page
                #convert to CAPS
                Inputelement = driver.find_element_by_id('id_fullname')
                time.sleep(1)
                String = Inputelement.get_attribute('value')
                time.sleep(1)
                Inputelement.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a")
                Inputelement.send_keys(Keys.DELETE)
                time.sleep(1)
                Inputelement.send_keys(String.upper())
                #save and return
                driver.find_element_by_id('id_saveandreturn').click()

        else:
            print ('List has no courses')
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: couldn't you just store them as strings in a list or something?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. I would recommend using the index in each iteration rather trying to access the previously stored elements. If you are referring to the options in Original Post(OP) then change the `options` list to as below.

```
# Get the number of options
options = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='course-list']/li")
# iterate through each option
for optionCounter in range(len(options)):
    # get the option here based on index
    option = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//*[@class='course-list']/li)[" + str(optionCounter) + "]")
    # continue working with option from here
```